# Getting Security error while altering table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called borrowlist. When I try to drop a column I get an **error** that says :

```
Cannot find the object "borrowlist" 
Because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."
```

Query : USE Test

```
alter table borrowlist DROP column MEMBERFULLNAME
```

Comment: SQL Server management studio 2008

Comment: If you do not have permissions to an object you will not be able to see it anywhere in the management studio. Only thing you can do is get access rights from the DBA, using grant command. If you have access to administrator account you can do it yourself.

Comment: @Nilesh is right. you do not have permisstion.

Comment: just for testing purpose i have only created DB and table.